# IOTA added to the address but immediately withdrawn from my address

Tags: transaction, tangle, bitfinex

I need your support to understand my missing IOTA. I transferred 356 iota from Binance to Bitfinex. The transaction was confirmed in Tangle explorer ( Transaction id CXQCVWYJ9WPDTMFEVEGOIQGILZMFHBPHPWY9KICASGJDSUSGBCPTGTJILUDUPDZMXRERGYQMLHOY99999)

The funds never reached my wallet on Bitfinex. When I checked the transaction I noticed that 356 iotas were added to my address but were almost immediately removed (taken out) from the deposit address. It’s been 12 days now and Bitfinex is not responding on my support tickets.

What can I do ?

Comment: That is not "your address" when you transferred to Bitfinex. When Bitfinex takes it out, they probably have processed it (and consolidated it into their main wallet). You cannot do anything else than ask their support where the iota went to...

Comment: Are you sure it was not his address? It arrived at December 11, 2017 07:27:19, he then saw it there, and then at December 11, 2017 17:11:10 it was taken away. https://thetangle.org/address/FOXMXDPHZ9OZOOW9IJF9VOTQXXBQDDIJVIK9ZVR9UIOPVMRDQGJCYUUZQUOHLQDQHNKADYWZGBBGNOFPX Six wallets were merged into a new one. Why would they want to consolidate wallets?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have already asked in the slack #help channel and a lot of people answered.
https://iotatangle.slack.com/archives/C5QA98BSA/p1514399779000038

This is duplicate.
Not really IOTA related but rather exchanges' inner process.
Please contact their support.

Comment: I think it would be better so send all the question-askers from Slack over to here.

Answer (score -3):

If you really transfered 356 iota (not MIOTA) I guess your iotas where eaten up by the fees bitfinex applies on deposits less than a 1000 USD equivalent.
See https://support.bitfinex.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004261674-Deposit-Fees .

Anyway this is not IOTA related ...

Comment: A little bit of effort would have shown that it's MIOTA https://thetangle.org/transaction/CXQCVWYJ9WPDTMFEVEGOIQGILZMFHBPHPWY9KICASGJDSUSGBCPTGTJILUDUPDZMXRERGYQMLHOY99999